# Need to output the remaining holidays in the txt file using python

Tags: python, reminders

happy holidays!

I am working on the project that needs to send reminders about public holidays 3 weeks in advance. I have completed this part and now need to add a function that will also send the remaining holidays for the year in addition to the upcoming holiday. Any tips or suggestions on how I can approach this will be greatly appreciated as I am new to coding!

Here is the code I have for now:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import calendar
import time
import smtplib as smtp
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.message import EmailMessage

holidayFile = 'calendar.txt'

def run(input):
    checkTodaysHolidays()

  
def checkTodaysHolidays(): 
    file = open(holidayFile, 'r')
    date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=21)).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    publicHolidayName = ''
    for line in file: 
        if date in line:
            publicHolidayName = " ".join(line.split()[1:])
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the format of the `calendar.txt` file?

Comment: @BenSoyka it's 2021/01/01 New Years

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use the `datetime` and `timedelta` modules you've already imported.

I would convert the data in your text file into an array, and  then build a function that compares today's date to the holidays in this list.

```
holidayFile = open('calendar.txt', 'r')
holidayLines = holidayFile.readlines()
holidayFile.close()

holidayNames = []
holidayDates = []

for x in range(0, len(holidayLines) ):
    # ... Get the date, first
    this = holidayLines[x].split(" ") # since we know they're formatted "YYYY/MM/DD Name of Holiday"
    rawdate = this[0]
    datechunks = rawdate.split("/") # separate out the YYYY, MM, and DD for use
    newdate = (datechunks[0] ,datechunks[1] , datechunks[2])

    holidayDates.append(newdate)

    # ... then get the Name
    del this[0] # remove the dates from our split array 
    name = "".join(this)

    holidayNames.append(name)
```

So in the block before our function, I:

- 1: Open the file and store each line, then close it.
- 2: Iterate through each line and separate out the date, and store the touples in an array.
- 3: Save the name to a separate array.

Then we do the comparison.

```
def CheckAllHolidays():
    returnNames = [] # a storage array for the names of each holiday
    returnDays = [] # a storage array for all the holidays that are expected in our response

    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    threeweeks = timedelta(weeks=3)
    for x in range(0, len(holidayDates) ):

        doi = holidayDates[x] # a touple containing the date of interest 
        year = doi[0]
        month = doi[1]
        day = doi[2]
        holiday = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)

        if holiday > today:
            # convert the holiday date to a date three weeks earlier using timedelta
            returnDays.append( holiday - threeweeks )
            returnNames.append( holidayNames[x] )
        else:
            pass # do nothing if date has passed
    return(returnDays, returnNames)
```

What I did here is I:

- 1: Create an array inside the function to store our holiday names.
- 2: Convert the date from the previous array into a `datetime.datetime()` object.
- 3: Compare two objects of like kind in an `if` block, and
- 4: Return a list of dates three-weeks before each holiday, with names for the holidays that a reminder should be set for.

Then you're all set. You could call

```
ReminderDates = CheckAllHolidays()[0]
ReminderNames = CheckAllHolidays()[1]
```

and then use those two lists to create your reminders! `ReminderDates` would be an array filled with `datetime.datetime()` objects, and `ReminderNames` would be an array filled with string values.

I'm sorry my response was kinda long, but I really hope I was able to help you with your issue! Happy Holidays  <3